# PHP XPath check if empty

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have this PHP code:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML( $html );

$xpath = new DomXPath($document);

$tables = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'info')]");
$tableDom = new DomDocument();  
$tableDom->appendChild($tableDom->importNode($tables->item(0), true));
```

How can I check if the $tables variable contains something that we can work with in the $tableDom?

I tried it with:

```
if (!empty($tables)) {
    echo("</br>not empty</br>");
} else {
    echo("empty");
}

if (!$tablese) {
    echo("empty</br>");
}
```

However it always said its not empty, all trough the HTML doesn't contain a table with the class info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

```
if ($tables->length>0) {
    echo("</br>not empty</br>");
} else {
    echo("empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@naga is correct. `DOMXpath::query()` always return an instance of `DOMNodelist`. (Or an error for an invalid expression).

If the expression did not match you will receive an empty list. This is an object and `empty()` will return `false`.

`DOMNodeList::$length` contains the number of nodes in the list. So you can validate it an condition:

```
if ($tables->length > 0) {
```

Another approach is to use `foreach()`. You can always iterate the node list. If you only want to use a node from a specific position (the first node) you can limit it in the Xpath expression.

```
$tables = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'info')][1]");
$tableDom = new DomDocument();  
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $tableDom->appendChild($tableDom->importNode($table, true));
}
```